# Is it possible to configure log4net in a hierarchical manner similar to the way an app.config or web.config is processed by .NET environment

Tags: c#, log4net, configuration-files, log4net-configuration

We have a distributed system with lots and lots of services running. 
We currently ship a common log4net config file with each instance of an application. 
To modify logging on site for a range of applications the support and implementation staff find it tedious and error prone to have to modify config files all of which look exactly the same.

I'm wondering if it is possible to merge log4net configuration files together similar to the way .NET manages it's environment.config, machine.config, app.config & web.config; basically by starting at the Top of the tree and looking for and merging configurations at run time from the lower levels.

If it were possible we could then have a single location where we could add in a new  appender; and then modify each applications config file to enable just that appender.

I can't find anything in the log4net configuration examples that would enable this.

Has anyone any idea if this is possible; or maybe an alternative approach which could be used to achieve the same effect.

Comment: A REST service which applications query to receive their very own log4net configuration would pack all settings up in a single spot.

Comment: Thanks Alex; but no I won't be heading down that root. Too much can go wrong calling services (local or remote) to make it a viable solution in our environment; if it not available then your back to using local config etc and it just gets too confusing. I suppose I'm hoping for a proven local architectural solution to the issue; if there is one out there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any mechanism buit into Log4Net, but you could use the `XInclude` directive to include a (partial)  Xml file in your Log4Net config file.

Put your common logging bits in the partial, have the individual config files include the common partial Xml File

[The XML FAQ - 19. How do I include one XML file in another?](http://xml.silmaril.ie/includes.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Has possibilities; with a single files specifing the appenders and each local config just needing it's own root and including that file. I'll investigate it and see how i get on; but still hoping for the holy grail.

Comment: Some niggly issues with this. Basical XML management does not include support for Xinclude in the base .NET framework. But there are some alternatives which seem to work. You still need to watch the file; so you end up watching the file with just the application XML configuration; you can't tell lognet to use an XInclude reader; nor can you override it's implementation in lognet the class is sealed. Likewise it uses the .NET System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig which means I can't override the way it loads the XM; so I definately can't inject an XInclude reader. Pity :(